# Is it safe to incorporate a Star Wars Light Saber into a logo without permission?

Tags: logo, branding, legal

So I am trying to design a logo for a company, they have requested I incorporate a Star Wars light saber into the logo. I fear this may cause copyright problems.

Is it okay to use something like this in a logo? Or is it suggested you don't?

Is there a risk of litigation if I design a logo that includes recognisable elements from the Star Wars franchise?

Comment: I hear the Disney company (who now owns Star Wars) is pretty litigious.

Comment: I think you already *know* the answer. :)

Comment: The litigation force is strong with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a signed agreement from the rights holder allowing such use or if you can get the company counsel (i.e. lawyers) to sign off on it, then sure, use light-sabers. But without those, the company is taking a serious legal risk that could very well ruin the company. As always, we are not your lawyer and legal questions should always be directed towards an appropriate licensed legal professional.

Comment: I figured this was going to be the answer. I guess I will talk to the company and let them know it be best to keep Star Wars stuff out of the design.

Answer (score 0):

The only permissible use of someone else's copyrighted material I'm aware of is for fan fiction or tribute sort of use. But certainly not for profit.

Comment: What exact visual aspect of the Light Saber brand weapon would be considered copyright?  Various kinds of glowing or flaming swords predate Star Wars.  While copying the exact markings off a Light Saber weapon would be a violation of copyright, I don't know that a glowing blade coming off a cylindrical hilt would have sufficient novelty in and of itself to merit protection.